# Price range using php and javascript

Tags: javascript, php, filter, price

I've created an online store with php language.

I need the section to filter the price of the product (price range).

In the javascript section, I need to use the php variable instead of **from** and **to**.

My javascript code :

```
<script>
    $('.price_range').jRange({
    from: 0,
    to: 67390000,
    step: 50,
    format: '%s USD',
    width: 300,
    showLabels: true,
    isRange : true
});
</script>
```

### Please guide how to use the php variables in this JavaScript code

Comment: from: <?= phpvariablename ?>,

Answer (score 0):

You can do that by using below code:

```
<?php echo $price_range;?>
```

or

```
<?= $price_range ?>
```

Comment: Thank you my friend . The problem was solved